Как загрузить сайт на поддомен на timeweb, если домен привязан к тильде
Есть домен и поддомен с рег.ру. К домену привязан сайт на тильде. Как к поддомену привязать второй сайт на хостинге таймвеб? Делаю все впервые, поэтому сначала сделала неправильно. Добавила и сам домен, и поддомен на сайт таймвеба. На рег ру заменила dns серверы на таймвебовские. На поддомен загрузила нужный сайт - он заработал. Но сайт на тильде естественно слетел, потому что домен тоже оказался на таймвебе. Как в итоге можно сделать так, чтобы на домене был основной сайт на тильде, а на поддомене был сайт на таймвеб?
